# foreach show one specific result in one row

Tags: mysql, arrays, foreach

I got a foreach-loop, but want to show one echo next to one specific post, while the rest shows to every loop-element.

I got that far:

```
$query = mysql_query ($query); (this also gets a post_id)

$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$data[] = $row;

foreach ($data as $row):

echo "Date", "post", "vote";
```

I now dont want the vote to be shown, in just one special row, if

```
$row = $query_row[0].
```

I tried

```
$query_row= ( find the post_id of the row, where the user voted)

if ($row['post_id'] == $query_row[0]) {

echo 'u voted';}

else {

echo 'vote';
}
```

Unfortunately, this would show up under every post, not just the post, where the user voted. Any ideas, how to echo "u voted", under just this one post_id?

Comment: Thank you rikh and Shakti Singh, now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you meant to say something like

```
if ($row->id == $query_row[0]->id)
```

The sample code you provide is incomplete though, so it isn't clear what's what...

Answer (score 0):

You should use `==` for equality checking, Use `=` for value assignment

```
if ($row == $query_row[0]) {
```